# Magento 2.4 admin keep on infinite loading

Tags: javascript, requirejs-config.js, magento2.4.1

I updated my magento from 2.1 to 2.4 .

My admin panel keeps on loading since long.

Below is error i see in console.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: mageTranslationDictionary
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:166)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

It is calling some js file : adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mageTranslationDictionary.js

which gives 404 , i can not see any such js file .

Please help me with it

Comment: How have you upgraded from 2.1 to 2.4? I've upgraded multiple sites to m2.4, but I couldn't get this kind of issue! So, asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to deploy the static content on particular store
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US